# Virtual member functions and std::tr1::function: How does this work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, tr1

Here is a sample piece of code. Note that `B` is a subclass of `A` and both provide a unique `print` routine. Also notice in `main` that both `bind` calls are to `&A::print`, though in the latter case a reference to `B` is passed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/functional>

struct A
{
    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cerr << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    virtual void print()
    {
        std::cerr << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    typedef std::tr1::function<void ()> proc_t;

    A a;
    B b;

    proc_t a_print = std::tr1::bind(&A::print, std::tr1::ref(a));
    proc_t b_print = std::tr1::bind(&A::print, std::tr1::ref(b));

    a_print();
    b_print();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I see compiling with GCC 4.2:

```
A
B
```

I would consider this correct behavior, but I am at a loss to explain how it is working properly given that the `std::tr1::function`s were bound to `&A::print` in both cases. Can someone please enlighten me?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answers. I am familiar with inheritance and polymorphic types. What I am interested in is what does `&A::print` *mean*? Is it an offset into a vtable, and that vtable changes based on the referred object (in this case, `a` or `b`?) From a more nuts-and-bolts perspective, how does this code behave correctly?

Comment: If this uses TR1, it should be tagged C++0x

Comment: @John: this code is C++ compiled under gcc 4.2 and doesn't touch C++0x. Could you clarify your position a bit please?

Comment: @fbrereto: Everything in the `tr1` namespace comes from the standard library proposals in the C++0x draft standard; specifically, those from Technical Report 1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1

Comment: @fbereto:  If you are using TR1 facilities, you are by definition using C++0x.  TR1 *is* C++0x

Comment: @John:  No, TR1 is not C++0x.  TR1 is a set of libraries that was proposed in 2005.  C++0x is the new revision of the standard to be published (hopefully) in 2011.  The TR1 libraries are not part of the C++ standard library, which is why they are all in the `std::tr1` namespace, not the `std` namespace.  The TR1 libraries have been included in the C++0x standard library (and for that they have been moved to the `std` namespace).

Comment: My understanding of TR1 is that it is a series of proposed extensions that will be included in C++0x, but TR1 is not the sum difference between C++0x and C++. These are extensions that compiler vendors are allowed to add to their current C++ implementations but are not required to do so. The use of the TR1 extensions in the code above does not make it C++0x code, just C++ code that leverages the optional C++ TR1 library extensions.

Comment: I did not intend to suggest that TR1 is the sum difference between C++ and C++0x, as it clearly is not.  I still maintain however, if you are using TR1 features, you are using C++0x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in the same manner as it would have worked with plain member function pointers. The following produces the same output:

```
int main ()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    typedef void (A::*fp)();
    fp p = &A::print;
    (a.*p)(); // prints A
    (b.*p)(); // prints B
}
```

It would have been surprising if boost/tr1/std::function did anything different since they presumably store these pointers to member functions under the hood. Oh, and of course no mention of these pointers is complete without a link to [the Fast Delegates article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx).

Comment: When I saw this question that article was the first thing I thought of!  Very interesting and thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Because `print()` is declared `virtual`, `A` is a polymorphic class.  By binding to the `print` function pointer, you will be calling through an `A` pointer, much in the same way as:

```
A* ab = &b;
ab->print();
```

In the `->print` call above, you would expect polymorphic behavior.  Same it true in your code as well.  And this is a Good Thing, if you ask me.  At least, most of the time. :)

Comment: You are binding not only to print(), which behaves polymorphically as noted here, but also to the object to call it from.  The type of the object comes into play because of that second binding.